# #define an object with no value

Tags: c, typedef

I am now read some c code. And is not very clear about the "#define someting" expression.

For example, I saw this code:

```
typedef enum cairo_path_op {
    CAIRO_PATH_OP_MOVE_TO = 0,
    CAIRO_PATH_OP_LINE_TO = 1,
    CAIRO_PATH_OP_CURVE_TO = 2,
    CAIRO_PATH_OP_CLOSE_PATH = 3
} __attribute__ ((packed)) cairo_path_op_t; /* Don't want 32 bits if we can avoid it. */


#ifndef __GNUC__
#define __attribute__(x)
#endif
```

I take attention to the "**__*attribute*__**(x)". since in other header file , the "**__*attribute*__**(x)" is defined with no value, but how it take effect in the enum  "cairo_path_op" define?

Comment: And then the meaning of it exist?

Comment: Since there is a `#ifndef __GNUC__` , `#define __attribute__(x)` is only defined for non-GCC compiler. I am not sure about the purpose of it tho.

Comment: `__attribute__` is a GCC-specific construct which would not be recognized (and cause errors) with other compilers. But is this actually the order of definitions in the header file?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood -- on GCC, the compiler recognizes `__attribute__`. See the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for portability reasons.

`__attribute__()` is a GCC extension for modifying various properties and behavior of functions, variables, types, etc.

If a non-GCC-compatible compiler tries to compile code that uses this extension, it won't able to do so and will throw a syntax error.

In order to avoid this, the author of the code makes the preprocessor replace this keyword with nothing if `__GNUC__` is not defined (i. e. if the compiler is not a GCC-compatible one), so that the code builds on a bigger variety of platforms.

Comment: that wouldn't work. he said it's in another file. surely it gets included first.

Comment: @larsmans This code has a few strange aspects and in general it's hard to make sense of it (for example, see my post scriptum). Maybe this applies to certain attributes only (which are used afterwards).

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `#ifndef` is the right thing, since we would want the `__attribute__` to come to nothing for compilers that don't support it.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Oh yes. I don't know why I added that nonsense. Perhaps I just got confused by all the stupid comments.